# Setting Nuget package target path for item in MSBuild project

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I am trying to put .targets and .props files into the build directory of my Nuget package. I know how to do this with a .nuspec file but I was hoping to do it in my MSBuild project file.

I can find no documentation of how to do this but Microsoft developers appear to be doing it in the repo "core-setup" with the file [Microsoft.NETCore.App.pkgproj](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/blob/master/src/pkg/projects/Microsoft.NETCore.App/Microsoft.NETCore.App.pkgproj).

```
<File Include="$(PropsFile)">
  <TargetPath>build/$(NETCoreAppFramework)</TargetPath>
</File>
```

When I try to replicate the usage above, the build succeeds but the element is apparently ignored because no build directory exists in the Nuget package. Is there some trick to using this? Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

(I am using MSBuild 15.3.409.57025 which I believe is the latest release.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish my objective.  I'm still unclear how it worked in the file I referenced above but I am okay with that being a mystery.

```
<Content Include="MyTargets.targets">
    <Pack>true</Pack>
    <PackagePath>build</PackagePath>
</Content>
```