# Project SDK (.Net Standard): Official way to create a nuget package that includes msbuild targets

Tags: sdk, package, nuget, project, target

Visual Studio 2019, .Net Standard 2.0

How do I include a custom msbuild targets file for the consuming project?
What is the official supported way of doing this?

I've already tried:

- modifying the csproj file as per ([Setting Nuget package target path for item in MSBuild project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820951/setting-nuget-package-target-path-for-item-in-msbuild-project))
- trying to specify a nuspec file as per (https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/11/11/build-tools-in-nuget/)

Nuspec:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>TestingNugetContent</id>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
    <title>Blah</title>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Blah</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="Immutable\*.*" target="content/Immutable/" />
    <file src="Build\*.*" target="build/netstandard2.0/" />
  </files>
</package>
```

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <NoPackageAnalysis>true</NoPackageAnalysis>
    <NuspecFile>TestingNugetContent.nuspec</NuspecFile>
    <IntermediatePackDir>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/bin/$(Configuration)/publish/</IntermediatePackDir>
    <PublishDir>$(IntermediatePackDir)$(TargetFramework)/</PublishDir>
    <NuspecProperties>publishDir=$([MSBuild]::NormalizeDirectory($(IntermediatePackDir)))</NuspecProperties>
    <Version>1.0.10</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="build\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="build\**" />
    <None Remove="build\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="build\netstandard2.0\TestingNugetContent.targets" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PublishAll" BeforeTargets="GenerateNuspec">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_TargetFramework Include="$(TargetFrameworks)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Targets="Publish" Properties="TargetFramework=%(_TargetFramework.Identity)" />
  </Target>


</Project>
```

Checking the consumer's <***>.csproj.nuget.g.targets file the import project tag for this custom target is missing after installing the Nuget package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs, [the props and targets file names must match the package id exactly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package). Your `nuspec` lists the `<id>` as `TestingNugetContent`, so the files must be `TestingNugetContent.props` and `TestingNugetContent.targets`. They should be either directly in the `build/` folder in the package, or the `build/<tfm>/` folder (I prefer to be more explicit, so I appriciate you used the `netstandard2.0` TFM). Now, your csproj appears to specify a `build\netstandard2.0\TestingNugetContent.targets`, which looks correct, so I can only guess that it wasn't packed into the correct location somehow.

I don't currently have time to show an example on how to pack it, but you can inspect the contents of your `nupkg` using [NuGet package explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/nuget-package-explorer/9wzdncrdmdm3?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), or just opening it up as a zip file, see what's "wrong", then adjust your project and try again.

FYI, you shouldn't need to use a nuspec at all, you can use the [MSBuild `PackagePath` metadata on items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#including-content-in-a-package) to specify where MSBuild items are packed. It's unclear to me what the purpose of your `PublishAll` target is supposed to be. If you added it as part of trying to get your targets file included, you can remove it.